# Loop and remove specific rows in python with conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

I want to remove all rows of the dataframe that don't have values 'X1' and '1' here is an example of the input and output with the following dataframe :

This is the dataframe I made:

```
d = {1: [0,0,0, 1,0], 2: [0,0,0, 1,0], 3:[0,0,0,1,0], 4:[0,0,1,1,0], 5:[0,0,1,'X1',0],
     6:[1,0,1,'X1',0],7:[1,0,1,'X1',0],8:[1,0,1,'X1',0],9:[1,0,'X1',0,pd.NaT]}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=range(1,6))
d

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   X1
4   1   1   1   1   X1  X1  X1  X1  0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   NaT
```

This is the code I made:

```
for column in d.columns:
    index_names = d[(d[column] == 1) | (d[column]== 'X1')]
      
index_names

    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   X1
```

It doesn't work very well! It considers just the last column and doesn't remove the fourth row.
Does anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try via boolean masking:

```
#your condition:
m=(d.eq(1).any(1)) | (d.eq('X1').any(1))

#Finally:
d=d[m]
#OR
d=d.loc[m]
```

output of `d`:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   X1
4   1   1   1   1   X1  X1  X1  X1  0
```